# Not able to call one event handler from another event handler in Backbone view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, event-handling

I am using Backbone.js and want to call one eventhandler function from another but I am not able to do so.

Here is my code --

```
events: {
    'click a#SignInBtn': 'signIn',
    'keyup': 'enterAndSignIn'
},
signIn: function (e) {
    console.log("function called");
},

enterAndSignIn: function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        signIn(e);
    }
}
```

Here I am caling `signIn` function from `enterAndSignIn` function But I am not able to do so. I have tried different ways but not able to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think the solution is pretty straightforward. In order to call 'signIn' from 'enterAndSignIn', you have to call `this.signIn(e);`